# Linux Circular Video Buffer

Tags: linux, camera, block-device

I have a 5MP 2592×1944 pixel camera that writes to GPU via DMA or to a YUV4:2:2 data file.

As this is quite non standard nearly all camera viewing applications can not handle this data and I would only be able to analyze the data after recording. I had the idea of setting up a ring buffer in /dev/ that is 2 frames large (2592x1944x1.5x2) 14763kb, and dump the video into that buffer. I could then access it like a standard video stream with video4linux programs and save/modify/resize it all I want to a new format.

The problem is how to setup a ring buffer and get the video to stream to it instead of yuv_file.data

Any sites that would show me how to set something like this up, or is this not even possible?